# Recursive multiplication in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have two values. How can I multiply the first value by the second, then multiply the result of this multiplication by the first number again, then multiply the result by the first number again, and so on? The number of such repetitions for example 7

I have two columns A and B.

- A: 1.65
- B: 10

And I need result like this in result column:

Result:

```
16,5, 27,2, 44,9, 74,1, 122,2, 201,7, 332,9
```

So the multiplication would be:

```
1.65 * 10 = 16,5
1.65 * 16,5 = 27,2
1.65 * 27,2 = 44,9
etc...
```

I guess I should use a recursive query but I am not sure how to write it I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Isn't this just exponentiation? In your example, you're getting 10 * 1.65^n for n between 1 and 7. If so, no need for recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive solution

> ```
> with CTE as (
>   select 
>    1.65 as val1,
>    10 as val2
> )
> , RCTE as (
>   select val1, val2, 1 as lvl
>   , cast(val1*val2 as decimal(38,16)) as result 
>   , cast(power(val1, 1)*val2 as float) as result2
>   from CTE
>   union all
>   select val1, val2, lvl+1
>   , cast(val1*result as decimal(38,16))
>   , cast(power(val1, lvl+1)*val2 as float) 
>   from RCTE
>   where lvl < 7
> )
> select *
> from RCTE
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> val1 | val2 | lvl |               result | result2
> ---: | ---: | --: | -------------------: | ------:
> 1.65 |   10 |   1 |  16.5000000000000000 |    16.5
> 1.65 |   10 |   2 |  27.2250000000000000 |    27.2
> 1.65 |   10 |   3 |  44.9212500000000000 |    44.9
> 1.65 |   10 |   4 |  74.1200625000000000 |    74.1
> 1.65 |   10 |   5 | 122.2981031250000000 |   122.3
> 1.65 |   10 |   6 | 201.7918701562500000 |   201.8
> 1.65 |   10 |   7 | 332.9565857578125000 |     333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87eb068bb29a3dfbc3bbdd28f9361d9a)*

Comment: Thanks. And now with power.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.65(1.65(1.65*10)) = (1.65*1.65*1.65)*10 = 1.65^3 * 10
```

so for 7 repetitions

```
select power(1.65,7) * 10
```

Comment: Thinking the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will be able to get the last result 332.9. But how do I get all the intermediate values?

Comment: Join a Tally Table to provide the powers 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate many rows for each successive value you can try:

```
with
n as (
  select 1 as i, cast(10.0 as float) as v
 union all
  select i + 1, v * 1.65 from n where i < 10
)
select v from n order by i
```

Result:

```
 v                
 ---------------- 
 10               
 16.5             
 27.225           
 44.92125         
 74.1200625       
 122.298103125    
 201.79187015625  
 332.956585757812 
 549.37836650039  
 906.474304725644
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=571ebae8d8e26aed4b885c76313209a8).